# Make VirualHost accessible in local network

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, virtual-host, mamp

I'm using MAMP.

My httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
   DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/test"
   ServerName test
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost test
```

On my local machine I can access the `htdocs` folder with "localhost" and 127.0.0.1 and the `test` folder with "test".

When I feed the browser of another device in my local network with the IP Address I get the `htdocs` folder.

How to access the `test` folder from other devices in my local network?

Answer (score 1):

Link hostname test with LAN-IP, resolvable for other lan-hosts

Or create virthost with name equal to IP and symlink it's DocumentRoot to test folder

Comment: How to link hostname "test" to a LAN-IP?

Comment: DNS for lan-ips or add to every hosts-file

Comment: Hosts files not an option. How to DNS for LAN-ips?

Comment: Start DNS-server for LAN and add this server as first into resolvers list on every host